# Roblox.py Module Not Logging In

Tags: python, roblox

I am trying to use `roblox.py` to add some users to a database; however I can not log in. I have installed the module `pip install roblox.py` and imported it `import roblox`. I haves

```
import roblox
with roblox.RobloxSession(username="UserName", password="Password") as rbx:
     rbx.post_status("Testing!")
```

The resulting error is stating it can not log in due to a wrong password or username. Anyone know why or can help me?

Comment: You are probably using an incorrect username or password. Are you sure you typed them in correctly? And that the account exists?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that. The account exists and the password and username are correct. @AvivShai

Comment: Let's see the traceback.